# How to display JSON data in jQuery DataTables via Ajax?

Tags: json, yii, datatables, html-table

I've been trying to get my JSON data in jQuery DataTables component.

First I wrote a JavaScript and a view like the code shown below:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    ajax: "http://localhost/example22/index.php?r=site/display",
    table: "#example",
    fields: [{
        label: "Name:",
        name: "name"
    }, {
        label: "Designation:",
        name: "designation"
    }, {
        label: "Address:",
        name: "address"
    }, {
        label: "Salary:",
        name: "salary"
    }]
});

$('#example').DataTable({
    lengthChange: false,
    ajax: "http://localhost/example22/index.php?r=site/display",
    columns: [{
        allk: "name"
    }, {
        allk: "designation"
    }, {
        allk: "address"
    }, {
        allk: "salary"
    }],
    select: true
});
```

and a view like

```html
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

and the url that is provided contains the following  JSON data respectively

```js
{
    "allk": [
        {
            "name": "raju",
            "designation": "developer",
            "address": "he is from viswasapuram",
            "salary": "30000"
        },
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "designation": "designer",
            "address": "no idea",
            "salary": "100000"
        },
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "designation": "designer",
            "address": "no idea",
            "salary": "100000"
        },
        {
            "name": "suresh",
            "designation": "designer",
            "address": "fffswss",
            "salary": "1212"
        },
        {
            "name": "john",
            "designation": "designer",
            "address": "california",
            "salary": "3000000"
        },
        {
            "name": "suresh",
            "designation": "tester",
            "address": "he is from cheeran maanagar",
            "salary": "20000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me on how to use DataTables with this application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to specify property holding data in your JSON response.

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped other options ...
   ajax: {
       url: "http://localhost/example22/index.php?r=site/display",
       dataSrc: 'allk'
   },
   columns: [
       { data: "name"}, 
       { data: "designation"}, 
       { data: "address" }, 
       { data: "salary"}
   ]
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqkwco17/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

In Nodejs when you have a DataTable declared like this

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Parents Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

then your java script should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "../kidsinfo",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "kid_name" },
            { data: "class" },
            { data: "parents_name" },
            { data: "age" },           
        ],          
        iDisplayLength: 1,
        iDisplayStart: 0
    });
});
```

Important point to note here is that your json data from server is like this

```
[{"id":1,"kid_name":"John","class":"Hancock","parents_name":"dharam","age":"21"}]
```

then your javascript code should use the name `kid_name` from the json data received to relate the information you want to display in the column.

If the json data from the server is like this

```
{
    "info": [{
        "id": 1,
        "kid_name": "John",
        "class": "Hancock",
        "parents_name": "dharam",
        "age": "21"
    }]
}
```

then your java script should have  `dataSrc: "info"`